# PerfView Callers is showing "Root", why?

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, perfview

I'm trying to figure out a CPU performance problem using PerfView, my application is an Asp.Net Core 2.2 running on IIS. According to this video https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PerfView-Tutorial/PerfView-Tutorial-2-A-Simple-CPU-Performance-Investigation the "Caller" is the main point to find the performance problem, but in my collections it's showing just a "ROOT" entry and it's not expandable, see: 
[image]

Any help?

Tks

Answer (score 0):

The view in your screenshot is showing "Methods that call `module coreclr <<coreclr?>>`" so as you expand the tree, it's showing you what called the current item. `ROOT` is the end of the line because nothing called that, which is why you can't expand beyond that.

The item above `ROOT` is the `dotnet` process that started your assembly.